# Lightning : Select isnt working & drop down isnt showing any values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" default="Red"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadOptions}" />
<lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select a color:" aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
        <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
     </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {

    var opts= ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
     opts.push("Lemon"); 
     component.set("v.options", opts);
}
})
```

Comment: change text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" to text="{!item}" value="{!item}"

Comment: you didnot push the array with label and value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also add label and value in the array

```
({
loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {

      var opts = [
            { value: "Banana", label: "Banana" },
            { value: "Orange", label: "Orange" },
            { value: "Apple", label: "Apple" },
          { value: "Mango", label: "Mango" }
         ];
     component.set("v.options", opts);
}
})
```

Comment: If your problem get resolved please mark it solve. It will helpful for other.

Comment: same code I have tried before posting that question https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm ..I got output..but if I do like this why iam not getting output

Comment: Because select options has combination of value and label. Label which visible on UI .